# Parsing a text file with a special markup

Tags: python, parsing, tags, markup

I need to parse a `DSL` file using Python. A DSL file is a text file with a text having a special markup with tags used by [ABBYY Lingvo](http://www.lingvo.com/).

It looks like:

```
activate
    [m0][b]ac·ti·vate[/b] {{id=000000367}} [c rosybrown]\[[/c][c darkslategray][b]activate[/b][/c] [c darkslategray][b]activates[/b][/c] [c darkslategray][b]activated[/b][/c] [c darkslategray][b]activating[/b][/c][c rosybrown]\][/c] [p]BrE[/p] [c darkgray] [/c][c darkcyan]\[ˈæktɪveɪt\][/c] [s]z_activate__gb_1.wav[/s] [p]NAmE[/p] [c darkgray] [/c][c darkcyan]\[ˈæktɪveɪt\][/c] [s]z_activate__us_1.wav[/s] [c orange] verb[/c] [c darkgray] [/c][b]{{cf}}\~ sth{{/cf}} [/b]
    [m1]{{d}}to make sth such as a device or chemical process start working{{/d}}
    [m2][ex][*]• [/*][/ex][ex][*]{{x}}The burglar alarm is activated by movement.{{/x}} [/*][/ex]
    [m2][ex][*]• [/*][/ex][c darkgray] [/c][ex][*]{{x}}The gene is activated by a specific protein.{{/x}} [/*][/ex]
    {{Derived Word}}[m3][c darkslategray][u]Derived Word:[/u][/c] ↑<<activation>>{{/Derived Word}}
    {{side_verb_forms}}[m3][c darkslategray][u]Verb forms:[/u][/c] [s]x_verb_forms_activate.jpg[/s]{{/side_verb_forms}}
```

Now I see the only option to parse this file using `regexps`. But I doubt if it can be achieved since tags in that format has some hierarchy, where some of them are inside others.

I can't use special `xml` and `html` parsers. They are perfect in creating a tree-structure of the document, but they are designed for special tags of `html` and `xml`.

What is the best way to parse a file in such a format? Is there any Python library for that purpose?

Comment: "DSL" is a generic term.  Which **specific** DSL is this?  What is the domain?  Is there an applicable standard?  When you Googled "Parse *D* Python" (where *D* is the applicable standard definition for the DSL) what did you get?

Comment: It's a dictionary file format of a program very popular in Russia. It's their own format and the file has `.dsl` extintion. All the information is in Russian, so I don't think it's a good idea to post link to description here.

Comment: I thought there could be some universal module to parse text files with tags. So I decided to ask here.

Comment: "text file with tags"?  That's way too vague to have any meaning.  JSON, LaTex, RTF are all "text file with tags".  There's no "universal parser".  You only need to use the  *name* of the applicable standard for  the DSL to search for a parser.  If none can be found with Google, then it does not exist.  There is no magical "text with tags" since this is too open, too vague, too ill-defined a description.

Comment: @S.Lott  Thanks. There is nothing I can find on Google. It's their local standard. I thought theire could be some engine which allows to create a tree basing on nesting tag structure (by providing the text and tag list (in this case the majority of tags are in square brackets)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "some engine which allows to create a tree basing on nesting tag structure".

Look at http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

You may be able to define the syntax quickly and easily as a set of Lexical rules and some grammar productions.

If you don't like that one, here's a list of alternatives.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

Comment: Thanks! At least I know now it way too complicated. I think I would stick with RegExps to exctract only some parts that I need. But your anser is what probably other people will be looking for when they need to parse a markup text file with tags.

Comment: "I think I would stick with RegExps".  Often that only makes one problem into two problems.  You need to look at PLY for this kind of thing before you try regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Using RegExp for this for something other than trivial use will give heartache and pain.

If you insist on using a RegEx (NOT RECOMMENDED), look at the methods used [HERE](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/REX.html) on XML

If by ".dsl" you mean the ABBRY or Lingvo dict format, you may want to look at [stardict.](http://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/) It can read the ABBRY dsl format.

Comment: Yes, it's Lingvo format. I need to extract some data for myself from DSL file and I want to do it most efficiently.

Comment: There are a couple of projects out there to convert Lingo to something else. Look there first. Define a YACC / LEX grammar would be a second choice. [S.Lott gave a couple of links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339446/parsing-a-text-file-with-a-special-markup/7339662#7339662). Avoid regex for this unless you are just trying to separate out full sections I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I chose the answer of @S.Lott because I think it will be useful for those who will face some other markup text format with tags they need to parse. Your answer of much help too!

Comment: I need to extract some information from about 3000 word cards (cards with key-words) to add it to the programs I use to learn English words. I wanted to do it using copy-paste method. But then I decided it's a good idea to use Python not to do mechanical work and to learn Python better.